How to get secret key from docusign through code
we are implementing the docusign connect functionality to receive updates from Docusign. for doing that we need to configure secret key under "connect keys" section and use it in our code to verify the validity/authenticity when docusign sends completed event. would like to know if we can achieve the same process through API.
Have tried exploring documentation but not found anything.

See updated answer.

Unfortunately that API is not public.
Update
Depending on your use case, the new Managing HMAC for multiple accounts feature may help you out.
It enables you to (manually) create an HMAC secret in one account, but then use that secret for the HMAC signatures from other accounts. You create the Webhook configurations in the other accounts programmatically. See the docs (link above) for more info.
